# Can I read label value in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

A label represents the address of the first byte following it, but can I read its value? For example can I do the following?

```
some_label:
    mov eax, some_label    ; this will move the address of mov into eax?
```

Comment: Well, did you try it?

Comment: @harold I am working on a function to output the value of a register or a memory address (still not finished), so even if I try it I can't find what the content of eax will be :)

Comment: What assembler are you using? The syntax varies, but what you show should be valid for `nasm`.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart I am using FASM and GNU Assembler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you show will work in e.g. `nasm`, but the result may not be what you expect.

A little more information into what you're writing would help this answer be more specific. (Typical user-mode ELF application? Stand-alone binary blob? Something else?)

Because the assembler doesn't know where (in the address space) your code may be running, the instruction you've written will cause a *relocation* to be generated by the assembler (if your output format supports it).

If your environment does support relocations, (e.g. an ELF object file produced by `nasm -f elf`) then that should be fine; `eax` will match what `eip` was prior to executing that instruction. This works because that instruction was fixed-up by the loader - a relocation was applied.

If your environment does *not* support relocations, (e.g. a raw binary file, or other non-hosted environment) then you have a problem.  If that instruction is at offset 0x100 in your binary blob, then `eax` will get the value `0x100` - certainly not the actual address you're executing at.  To remedy this, you need to do the relocation yourself.  Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do this on x86 (32-bit). You have to do something like this:

```
    call .getbase
.getbase:
    pop ebx
    sub ebx, .getbase

    ;; Now ebx has the base address of your linked application/blob

some_label:
    mov eax, some_label
    add eax, ebx

    ;; Now eax has the (run-time) address of some_label
```

The x86_64 instruction set added a RIP-relative addressing scheme, which makes this much easier:

```
some_lable:
    lea rax, [rel some_label]
```